# How to fix serial communication?

Tags: serial

I am trying to use serial communication to open and close a Blue Robotics Newton gripper. The gripper works with normal commands, but when I try to use serial communication to control it, it is extremely slow and my commands do not correspond to the action I would like. For example, I'll write a "o" in the serial monitor and the gripper will not open.

Does anyone know what is wrong?

```
#include "Servo.h"

#define GRIPPER_PWM_PIN   10    // Gripper PWM output pin
#define OPEN_TIME         5.0   // Gripper open time (seconds)
#define CLOSE_TIME        5.0   // Gripper close time (seconds)

#define OPEN_PWM_US       1100  // Gripper open PWM output (us)
#define CLOSE_PWM_US      1900  // Gripper close PWM output (us)
int incomingByte =0; // for incoming serial data
Servo gripper;

void setup() {
 // Attach gripper to proper pin
 gripper.attach(GRIPPER_PWM_PIN);
 Serial.begin(9600); // opens serial port, sets data rate to 9600 bps

}

void loop() {
 if (Serial.available() > 0){
   incomingByte = Serial.read();
   if (incomingByte == 'o') 
   {
     // Open the gripper
     gripper.writeMicroseconds(1100);
     // Let the gripper open up (microseconds)
     delay(OPEN_TIME*1000);
   }
   
   if (incomingByte == 'c') 
   {
     // Close the gripper
     gripper.writeMicroseconds(1900);
     // Let the gripper close for a while (microseconds)
     delay(CLOSE_TIME*1000);
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: maybe remove the 5 seconds delays or don't send commands at that time.

Comment: Why do you even have this 5 second delay? I don't see any sense in it.

Comment: Ok this worked - how do I accept it as an answer!? Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a big 5s delay in your code, right after both serial commands. You don't need a delay there; it does not do anything. But it makes your code unresponsive. So you can simply remove it.

I guess you wanted to do some timed thing there and accidentally left it there.  But in general you should not use any big `delay()` in any code. As you have seen, it makes your code unresponsive, as the Arduino doesn't do anything during this time. Instead look at the `BlinkWithoutDelay` example, that comes with the Arduino IDE (Its a really important principle to learn). It uses the `millis()` function (or alternatively the `micros()` function) to check, if it is time to do something. If yes, it will execute this, if not, it will exit fast and give the rest of the code an opportunity to execute. Much like you would bake a pizza: You start the baking and then regularly  check the clock, if it is time to take the pizza out. In between you can do other things, like reacting go messages on your phone. Its the same principle, just in code.

Comment: Great advice! Thank you very much